AWS Batch Job Metric confusion
This is our current workflow:
File is dropped in S3 Bucket => a Lambda is triggered => Lambda then starts a Batch Job to process the file => 
Batch Job starts a task in ECS => an Instance is created => ECR Image is run on that instance =>
Processing of file get completed => Instance is destroyed => Task is stopped => Batch Job is completed

We are using instance type: c6g.medium, with 1 vCpu and 1GB memoery.
After the batch job was done, I went to check the Maximum CPU utilisation for that task. I waited for 10 minutes to show it. It shows sometimes 0% CPU utilisation and sometimes 90% CPU utilisation. Then I went to see the CPU utilisation of the instance which was used for that task. There CPU utilisationn is 15-17%. This is understandable. What I don't understand Why there is difference in Maximum CPU utilisation in ECS=> Cluster => Metrics vs Ec2 Instance => Metrics? They both are supposed to show the metrics for same thing.
